# Plan Cache size for SQL Server EXPRESS.

Tags: sql-server-2008

I use SQL EXPRESS on some of our servers. It has a limitation of 1.5GB for memory. How to find Plan Cache size for EACH database in SQL Express?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since no one answered....

```
SELECT SUM(size_in_bytes) * 1.0 / POWER(1024, 2) PlanCacheSize FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans;
go 

SELECT objtype AS [CacheType]
        , count_big(*) AS [Total Plans]
        , sum(cast(size_in_bytes as decimal(18,2)))/1024/1024 AS [Total MBs]
        , avg(usecounts) AS [Avg Use Count]
        , sum(cast((CASE WHEN usecounts = 1 THEN size_in_bytes ELSE 0 END) as decimal(18,2)))/1024/1024 AS [Total MBs - USE Count 1]
        , sum(CASE WHEN usecounts = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Total Plans - USE Count 1]
FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans
GROUP BY objtype
ORDER BY [Total MBs - USE Count 1] DESC
go
```